# Iframe onClick unexpected behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have this script to load iframes onClick, but when I click on a link, it loads all the frames at the same time.

JS

```
$('.toggle-next-div').click(function(){
var iframe = $('.myiFrame');
iframe.attr("src", iframe.data("src")); 
});
```

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="toggle-next-div">Map</a>// iframe (1)
<iframe class="myiFrame" data-src="my-url" src="about:blank"></iframe>  
<a href="#" class="toggle-next-div">Map</a>// iframe (2)
<iframe class="myiFrame" data-src="my-url" src="about:blank"></iframe>
<a href="#" class="toggle-next-div">Map</a>// iframe (3)
<iframe class="myiFrame" data-src="my-url" src="about:blank"></iframe>
<a href="#" class="toggle-next-div">Map</a>// iframe (4)
<iframe class="myiFrame" data-src="my-url" src="about:blank"></iframe>
//...and so on.....
```

I'm expecting to load just one frame at time when I click on the relative link.

How to do that?

Comment: try using `var iframe = this.$('.myiFrame')`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.toggle-next-div').click(function () {
    var iframe = $(this).next('.myiFrame');
    iframe.attr("src", iframe.data("src"));
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMuir/6XnwC/

Hope this helps.